# Сделать традиционный выделенный маршрут в asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Все облазил, не могу сообразить, как сделать следующее:
1. Если человек в адресной строке пишет: `mysite.ru/home/index` или просто `mysite.ru`, то его перенаправляет на контроллер `HomeController->Index`. Тут все как обычно.
2. Но если человек пишет: `mysite.ru/hello` или что либо другое вместо hello, то ему надо вернуть просто строку. При этом надо прочесть что же написано в адресе (в данном примере написано hello).

```
            // Пример как я пробовал  сделать в методе Startup->Configure через Map.
            // Тут 2 минуса: не известно как получить то, что написано в маршруте (в примере это hello) и здесь придется на старте приложения задать все строки, а они могут быть любые.
            app.Map("/visexp",
            (appBuilder) => 
            {

                appBuilder.Run(async (context) =>
                {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("строка -" + ПеременнаяСhello);
                });
            });
```

Пример, что должно быть: человек пишет `mysite.ru` - отрабатывает `HomeController`; Человек пишет `mysite.ru/radomtext` - у него обновляется страница где просто написано `Строка - radomtext`

Comment: для каких целей скажите

Comment: Если вам нужно получать данные из [урла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL), то, думаю, нужно задавать эти данные не в **path** (_путь_), а в **query** (_параметры_). То есть будет задаваться после знака `?`.

Comment: @Саске Цель убрать контроллер и параметры из ссылки, чтобы ссылка была короче. Фактически, когда пишется `mysite.ru/radomtext` должен отрабатывать контроллер с аргументом (radomtext), который должен возращать не IActionResult, а string

Comment: Фактически, при стандартной маршрутизации, ссылку можно было бы написать так: `mysite.ru/defaultController/GetString/radomtext`. Это дело нужно сократить до простого `mysite.ru/radomtext`.

Comment: Опасные штуки вы делаете... я когда-то делал такую задачу и решил, что хотя бы контроллер которотких оставлю, т.е. не `/hello`, а `/z/hello`. А тут вам лего попасть на долгий  дебаг вида "почему у меня метод идёт на дефолтный контроллер, а не куда надо"

Comment: @AK что-то не соображу как сделать `mysite.ru/z/hello`. Тогда для каждого рандомного текста типа "hello" придется метод отдельный писать, если оставить стандартную реализацию роутинга

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Чтобы сделать стандартный выделенный маршрут без второго слеша, то есть обращаться к контроллеру не так `mysite.io/home/index`, а так `mysite.io/index`, то в `Startup.cs` писать следующий роут:

   ```
       app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute( // роутинг на стандартный ноум контроллер всегда
               name: "default",
               template: "/{action=Index}/{id?}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home" });
       });
   ```
2. Чтобы сделать как я хотел, сохранить стандартный роутинг и одновременно на один конкретный контроллер отправлять все остальное, что не прошло по стандартному роутингу надо делать так:

   ```
           app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute( // почти стандартный роутинг, он автоматом на home/index не кидает.
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

           app.Run(async (context) => // если по стандартному маршруту ни чего не нашлось, то выполняется данный код
           {
               string url = context.Request.Path.Value.TrimEnd('/'); // получаем ссылку по которой перешли
               await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hi" + url);
           });

       });
   ```